# Drupal - block deleted - how to retrieve

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-blocks

We're running version 6.14 of Drupal (old, I know). On of our users recently deleted a block by accident in a series of rotating images. (Administer > site building > block). So now the block shows up as a blank, or "n/a".

She did manage to add another block in its place, but apparently that doesn't help - the n/a still displays. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Make regular backups and play on staging, not on live.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the new block the user created had a block number of "8", whereas the original block that was deleted had a number of "2". The fix was to go into custom themes for the homepage, edit page.tpl.php, and change the "module_invoke" to refer to the correct block.